# Bash Regex to extract everything between the last occurrence of a string (release-) and some characters (--)

Tags: regex, bash

I have multiple strings, where I want to extract everything between the last occurrence of a string (release-) and some characters (--). More specifically, for a sting like the following:

```
inte_integration-abc-abcde-abcdefg-release-release-PI_4.1-Sprint-3.1a--1.0.2-RELEASE
```

I want to have the following output:

```
PI_4.1-Sprint-3.1a
```

I created a regex online, which you can find [here](https://regex101.com/r/e6G7aB/2). There regex is the following:

```
.*release-(.*)--.*
```

However, when I am trying to use this script into a bash script, it wont work. [Here](http://tpcg.io/_BUHJSH) is an example.

```
artifactoryVersion="inte_integration-abc-abcde-abcdefg-release-release-PI_4.1-Sprint-3.1a--1.0.2-RELEASE"

 [[ "$artifactoryVersion" =~ (.*release-(.*)--.*) ]]

 echo $BASH_REMATCH[0]
 echo $BASH_REMATCH[1]
```

Will return:

```
inte_integration-abc-abcde-abcdefg-release-release-PI_4.1-Sprint-3.1a--1.0.2-RELEASE[0]
inte_integration-abc-abcde-abcdefg-release-release-PI_4.1-Sprint-3.1a--1.0.2-RELEASE[1]
```

Do you have any ideas about how can I accomplish my goal in bash?

Comment: The initial `.*` in your regex consumes everything form the beginning of your string up to `release`. The final .* consumes everything from the double-dash until the end of the string. `$BASH_REMATCH[0]` contains the whole matched pattern (i.e. the whole string). `$BASH_REMATCH[1]` contains the part of the pattern corresponding to the first open parentheses, i.e. also the whole string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the following:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

artifactoryVersion="inte_integration-abc-abcde-abcdefg-release-release-PI_4.1-Sprint-3.1a--1.0.2-RELEASE"
if [[ "$artifactoryVersion" =~ .*release-(.*)-- ]]; then
 echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]};
fi
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/hxEtD1)

Output:

```
PI_4.1-Sprint-3.1a
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use:

```bash
s='inte_integration-abc-abcde-abcdefg-release-release-PI_4.1-Sprint-3.1a--1.0.2-RELEASE'
rx='.*-release-(.*)--'
[[ $s =~ $rx ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"

PI_4.1-Sprint-3.1a
```

[Code Demo](https://ideone.com/cU4ExM)

Your regex appears correct but make sure to use `"${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"` to extract first capture group in the result.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples please try following BASH code with regex. I have also mentioned comments before executing each statement to understand each statement here.

```
##Shell variable named var being created here.
var="inte_integration-abc-abcde-abcdefg-release-release-PI_4.1-Sprint-3.1a--1.0.2-RELEASE"

##Mentioning regex which needs to be checked on later in program.
regex="(.*release-release)-(.*)--"

##Check condition on var variable with regex if match found then print 2nd capturing group value.
[[ $var =~ $regex ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
```

***Explanation of regex:*** Following is the detailed explanation for used regex.

- `regex="(.*release-release)-(.*)--"`:  Creating shell variable named `regex` in which putting regular expression `(.*release-release)-(.*)--`.
- Where regex is creating 2 capturing groups.
- First matching everything till release-release(with greedy match), which is followed by a `-`(not captured anywhere).
- Which is followed by a greedy match, which will basically match everything before `--` to get the exactly needed value.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it with shell parameter expansions (it's slower than a bash regex but it's standard):

```bash
artifactoryVersion='inte_integration-abc-abcde-abcdefg-release-release-PI_4.1-Sprint-3.1a--1.0.2-RELEASE'

result=${artifactoryVersion##*-release-}
result=${result%%--*}

printf %s\\n "$result"
```

```
PI_4.1-Sprint-3.1a
```

---

Or directly with a bash parameter expansion and extended globing:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s extglob

artifactoryVersion='inte_integration-abc-abcde-abcdefg-release-release-PI_4.1-Sprint-3.1a--1.0.2-RELEASE'

echo "${artifactoryVersion//@(*-release-|--*)}"
```

```
PI_4.1-Sprint-3.1a
```